# SSIS Package only inserts only about 1/4 of records from file when run on the Windows Task Scheduler or from a Batch File

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssms

I have an SSIS package that runs from the Windows Task Scheduler.  One of the files I worked with works fine when run manually but only inserts about 1/4 of the records from the file.  I am doing a simple Truncate Table and Insert.

Below is the batch file I am using to run from the Task Scheduler:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /F "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Code\DEV\SSIS_TMW_MANPOWERPROFILE\Package.dtsx" 
pause 5 
exit 0
```

All the other files I have seem to work fine but this one doesn't load fully.  It inserts exactly 848 records out of ~3400 each time I run the batch file from the Job Scheduler.  When I click the batch file to run it does the same thing.  Running it in SSMS it works fine and inserts all the records.  This is from SQL Server to Snowflake.  Below is what i get when running the batch file:

[image]

I looked at the 849th record to see if there was any junk but it doesn't appear to have any out of place commas or backslashes or any of the usual suspects.  The ETL worked fine yesterday and was inserting all the records.  Since it doesn't fail when I run it locally I can't really know what the issue is.

I tried using other numbers in the URL like 110, 130, etc.  It does work for other files though.  My flow is really basic.  Truncate and load: Source > Data Conversion > Inserts.  Just wondered if anyone else has encountered this issue and what they did to fix it.

Comment: Hi just to rule out if it is the data, can you delete the 848 rows from the file and see if it works for the remaining rows or it again breaks at 848.

Comment: You might also want to consider opening the file with an editor that allows you to see non-printable characters (like a hex editor).  There might be something present not visible to you in the file that's creating issues.